# How to list all available postfixes for a package?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Packages can have postfix versions in Python.
For example: `torch==1.12.1` vs `torch==1.12.1+cu111`.
Is there a way to list all the available postfixes for a given package?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this isn't possible because this depends on the index.
If you are running into an issue where you can't install a package with a given postfix, try checking if it has an extra index. (The `--extra-index-url` argument to pip).